# Springdata elasticsearch remapping id field to _id

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In java I have a domain class Foo. It has an id field. Springdata automatically maps this field to the field "id" and not "_id" because of it's name. Is there a way to remap this id to the _id field?

```
public class Foo  {
    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
    private String id;
}
```

So when I do findById(String id), the find by will use the id field in the domain object as opposed to the _id generated by elastic search.

I tried making the method named: findBy_Id(String id), but spring data library will complain that this field doesn't exist in the model. I didn't want to have to rename my id property in all my objects to _id to get this to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "Springdata automatically maps this field to the field "id" and not "_id" because of it's name."?

With the code you have elasticsearch will create a document with following schema which contains both _id & id field. _id is the part of ES default schema and it's value is picked up from the id field of Foo class.
 
    {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "323455",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "id": "323455"
        }
    }

Comment: edited my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Foo` class definition to define the index name and type parameters.

```
@Document(indexName = "foo",type = "foo")
public class Foo  {
    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
    private String id;
}
```

Assuming you are using Spring data. You must have created a `FooRepository` as shown below.

```
public interface FooRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Foo,String> {

}
```

You must be using `save` method to index `Foo` object in the elasticsearch.

```
Foo objFoo = new Foo();
objFoo.setId("123");

objFooRepository.save(objFoo);
```

Elastic search will index the document objFoo by creating a new index called foo and type foo.

```
{
    "_index": "foo",
    "_type": "foo",
    "_id": "123",
    "_score": 1,
    "_version": 1,
    "_source": {
        "id": "123"
    }
}
```

Use `findOne()` method of the repository to retrieve the indexed document.

```
Foo indexedFoo = repository.findOne(objFoo.getId());
```